# I'm getting Key error in python

Tags: python, dictionary

In my python program I am getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'variablename'
```

From this code:

```
path = meta_entry['path'].strip('/'),
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: `Key error` generally means the `key` doesn't exist. So,are you sure 'path' exist.?

Comment: Print the contents of `meta_entry` and ensure the key you want exists.

Comment: > If you don't want to have an exception but would rather a default value used instead, you can use the get() method_, 
such as `path = meta_entry.get('path', None)`. This is useful if `path` is not guaranteed to be present. . See @Adam's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10116571/1159167) and [KeyError](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError).

Answer (score 347, accepted):

A [`KeyError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) generally means the key doesn't exist. So, are you sure the `path` key exists?

From the official python docs:

**exception KeyError**

> Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of
>   existing keys.

For example:

```
>>> mydict = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
>>> mydict['a']
'1'
>>> mydict['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
>>>
```

So, try to print the content of `meta_entry` and check whether `path` exists or not.

```
>>> mydict = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
>>> print mydict
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

Or, you can do:

```
>>> 'a' in mydict
True
>>> 'c' in mydict
False
```

Comment: hmm...how would I do that? (Sorry for being a noob)
The app is hosted on google app engine and I don't have access to any files that it creates.

Comment: I have access to my code but none of the code that it creates or the engine uses

Comment: So, the code you posted `path = meta_entry['path'].strip('/'),` is it part of your code or the engine. If it is part of the engine i am afraid nothing can't be done.

Comment: @lonehangman: than just do `print meta_entry` and check if it contains `path` or not.

Comment: I'm quite new to python, could you please explain with more detail. Sorry for being a pest

Comment: @lonehangman: Can you please tell which part you are nt getting.

Comment: Where to put
>>> mydict = {'a':'1','b':'2'}
>>> print mydict
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}

Comment: As you suggested that `path = meta_entry['path'].strip('/'),` is part of the code you wrote. So, it means `meta_entry` is also the part of your code. Now you are expecting a defined output when running your code. So, just `print` the contents of `meta_entry` by writing `print meta_entry` in your python code. and execute it to see the result.

Comment: Ok I inserted the print meta_entry. Since I can't run it with python on my machine because it requires googles code I have to upload an run it. It works fine but I still get the error, where would meta_entry be printed to?

Comment: It should be printed on the browser when you hit the desired url.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [hello world gapp engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld) and try to play with that example a little. It will help you in two ways : 1--> better understanding of gapp engine and 2--> how to debug it

Comment: I left out a small detail...this error only happens when I upload a file from outside my browser(which is what I'm trying to achieve)

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you mean by `outside the browser`.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to make a way for files to be uploaded to dropbox without having to download software or use a browser to upload. For my tests I'm using windows network place. I can view and download files fine but I can't upload.

Comment: So why are you not using `dropbox python api`. I believe you can achieve you task by using that. Although I am not sure.

Comment: That's something else...when I access the url it request for a username and password. I tried mine but that didn't work so is it possible to print to an external url or a file?

Comment: I tried printing meta_entry. That doesn't exist. I didn't read this:
# make a fake Resource to ease our exporting

Comment: Adam Lewis solution is simple and efficient

Comment: I am calculating the false positive data-points using                                                       if y_pred_set2[5]==0 and y_test[5]==1:, but it results in the key-error. According to your explanation, this should only occur if key is not found in the set of existing keys, but the keys I am using are indices, there shouldn't be this problem with them, right?

Answer (score 167):

I fully agree with the Key error comments.  You could also use the [dictionary's get()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) method as well to avoid the exceptions.  This could also be used to give a default path rather than `None` as shown below.

```
>>> d = {"a":1, "b":2}
>>> x = d.get("A",None)
>>> print x
None
```

Comment: +1 for very relevant .get() comment. Looks like a good application of the Python EAFP (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission) instead of LBYL (Look Before You Leap) which I think is less Pythonic.

Answer (score 50):

For dict, just use

`if key in dict`

and don't use searching in key list

`if key in dict.keys()`

The latter will be more time-consuming.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is most likely caused by non-exsistent key.

In my program, I used setdefault to mute this error, for efficiency concern. 
depending on how efficient is this line

```
>>>'a' in mydict.keys()
```

I am new to Python too. In fact I have just learned it today. So forgive me on the ignorance of efficiency.

In Python 3, you can also use this function,

```
get(key[, default]) [function doc][1]
```

It is said that it will never raise a key error.

Comment: The get method is ancient, I think even 1.x dicts had it.  But I'm sure 2.7 already had it.

Answer (score 5):

Let us make it simple if you're using Python 3

```
mydict = {'a':'apple','b':'boy','c':'cat'}
check = 'c' in mydict
if check:
    print('c key is present')
```

If you need else condition

```
mydict = {'a':'apple','b':'boy','c':'cat'}
if 'c' in mydict:
    print('key present')
else:
    print('key not found')
```

For the dynamic key value, you can also handle through try-exception block

```
mydict = {'a':'apple','b':'boy','c':'cat'}
try:
    print(mydict['c'])
except KeyError:
    print('key value not found')
    mydict = {'a':'apple','b':'boy','c':'cat'}
```

Answer (score 3):

I received this error when I was parsing `dict` with nested `for`:

```
cats = {'Tom': {'color': 'white', 'weight': 8}, 'Klakier': {'color': 'black', 'weight': 10}}
cat_attr = {}
for cat in cats:
    for attr in cat:
        print(cats[cat][attr])
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
    KeyError: 'K'
```

Because in second loop should be `cats[cat]` instead just `cat` (what is just a key)

So:

```
cats = {'Tom': {'color': 'white', 'weight': 8}, 'Klakier': {'color': 'black', 'weight': 10}}
cat_attr = {}
for cat in cats:
    for attr in cats[cat]:
        print(cats[cat][attr])
```

Gives

```
black
10
white
8
```

Answer (score 1):

This means your dictionary is missing the key you're looking for. I handle this with a function which either returns the value if it exists or it returns a default value instead.

```
def keyCheck(key, arr, default):
    if key in arr.keys():
        return arr[key]
    else:
        return default


myarray = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}

print keyCheck('key1', myarray, '#default')
print keyCheck('key2', myarray, '#default')
print keyCheck('key3', myarray, '#default')
```

Output:

```
1
2
#default
```

Comment: Argh... horrible, horrible unpythonic code.  Don't write PHP code in Python: it's not an array, it's a dictionary (you may call it a hash, but array is right out).  And: dicts already have your "keyCheck" function:  instead of "keyCheck('key1', myarray, '#default')" you'd do "mydict.get('key1', '#default')"

Answer (score 0):

For example, if this is a number :

```
ouloulou={
    1:US,
    2:BR,
    3:FR
    }
ouloulou[1]()
```

It's work perfectly, **but**  if you use for example :

```
ouloulou[input("select 1 2 or 3"]()
```

it's doesn't work, because your input return string '1'. So you need to use **int()**

```
ouloulou[int(input("select 1 2 or 3"))]()
```