# Error in python function pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, keyerror

This is a function that returns an error at the line with `post['date']`.

This is the error:

```
in get_posts
    post['date'] = post['date'].strftime("%A, %B %d %Y at %I:%M%p")
KeyError: 'date'
```

What does it mean?

This is the function:

```
def get_posts(self, num_posts):

    cursor = self.posts.find({},{}).limit(num_posts) # Using an empty itable for a placeholder so blog compiles before you make your changes
    # XXX HW 3.2 Work here to get the posts
    l = []

    for post in cursor:
        print post          
        post['date'] = post['date'].strftime("%A, %B %d %Y at %I:%M%p")
        if 'tags' not in post:
            post['tags'] = [] # fill it in if its not there already
        if 'comments' not in post:
            post['comments'] = []

        l.append({'title':post['title'], 'body':post['body'], 'post_date':post['date'],
                  'permalink':post['permalink'],
                  'tags':post['tags'],
                  'author':post['author'],
                  'comments':post['comments']})

    return l
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting Key error in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyError: 'date'` means that `post` doesn't have the attribute `date`.