# KeyError - python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I'm using a dictionary in Python and trying to reference one of the data categories however I am getting a keyerror when running the code.

"Restock_Item" will be an eight digit number such as "12345670" which is in the dictionary so by using

```
stock[restock_item]['STOCK_LEVEL']
```

it would be referencing the dictionary like this:

```
stock[12345670]['STOCK_LEVEL']
```

But when doing this I get the error:

```
KeyError: 12345670
```

Here is the code:

```
restock_item = input("\nPlease enter the gtin code of the product you wish to restock. ")
    if restock_item.isdigit() == True:

        restock_level = input("How many items would you like to restock? ")
        while restock_item.isdigit() == True:

            restock_item = int(restock_item)
            newStockLevel = int(stock[restock_item]['STOCK_LEVEL']) # This is the line that gets the key error
            newStockLevel = newStockLevel + restock_level
            stock[restock_item]['STOCK_LEVEL'] = newStockLevel
```

Comment: `KeyError` means that no item in your dictionary has that key. Are you sure that what you're trying to retrieve exists?

Comment: `print` the dictionary. You'll find that you're trying to access a non-existent entry. Not much more to do

Comment: Are you creating stock[restock_item], or should it be there already? Or are you creating it unless it is already there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting Key error in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)

Comment: @MadPhysicist im sorry it's just i dont understand it in other contexts

Comment: @Sty i'm sure it exists because the dictionary retrieves data from a file and the file has that key in it

Comment: @Jérôme it should be there already, im just accessing a piece of data from the dictionary and assigning it to a variable

Comment: When you retrieved the dictionary from the file, did you also apply `int()` to this key?  `12345670` and `"12345670"` are not equivalent keys.

Comment: @jasonharper Yeah I just thought maybe that was the reason and i resolved the problem, thanks for the help :) i converted the variable to an int before i used it

Comment: You might want to 1/ Write that as an answer 2/ Accept your own answer so that this case is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments:

> When you retrieved the dictionary from the file, did you also apply int() to this key?
>   12345670 and "12345670" are not equivalent keys. – jasonharper
>
> Yeah I just thought maybe that was the reason and i resolved the problem, thanks for the help :) i converted the variable to an int before i used it – Heather Lara