# Error while Iterating through a list

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, append

```
[{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]
```

Thats my dict.

My code to make a list of values of dict_month

```
dict_month = []    
jan_month= []
for x in file_st:
    a=calendar.month_name[int(x['Start Time'][5:7])] #month name
    b=parser.parse(x['Start Time']).strftime("%a")  # day name
    dict_month.append({a:b})     # [{}]

for x in dict_month:
    jan_month.append(x['January'])
```

The error i get is

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-42-879788f99587> in <module>()
 23 
 24 for x in dict_month:
---> 25     jan_month.append(x['January'])
     26 

 KeyError: 'January'
```

Where is the code wrong? how do i correct it?

> output
>   [sun,sun,sun]

edit
[its a key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)  this should help.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What's `file_st`?

Comment: @UbdusSamad file_st has timestamp yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss

Comment: @WillDaSilva expected output is [sun,sun,sun]

Answer (score 2):

Hope it may help you:

```
dict_month = [{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]  

jan_month =  [x['January'] for x in dict_month]

>>>['Sun', 'Sun', 'Sun', 'Sun']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]
```

Is not a dict

a **dict** is something that is enclosed in **{}**

```
 {'January': 'Sun', 'January': 'Sun','January': 'Sun','January': 'Sun'}
```

Should be your dict

Anything enclosed in a **[]** is a **list**

So technically

```
[{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]
```

is a list, and each item of the list is a dict with **1 key,value pair**

```
x = [{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]

xyz = []

for y in x:
     xyz.append(y['January'])

print(xyz)
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a list and a dictionary,

Comment: A list is List literals are written within square brackets [ ] 
`x = [sun,mon,tue]` is a list

Comment: x = `{'January': 'Sun', 'January': 'Sun','January': 'Sun','January': 'Sun'}`
january here is the key and sun is the value `key:value`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m5l6DbRymIWK7U5u9Y45QeGXbMzwqLbY/view?usp=sharing       look at this error

Comment: `dict_month = [{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]
jan_month= []
for y in dict_month:
     jan_month.append(y['January'])

print (jan_month)
`

Answer (score 1):

dict_month is a list of dicts and values can be append in a new list which is jan_month.

```
>>> dict_month = [{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]
>>> jan_month = []
>>> for x in dict_month:
...     jan_month.append(x['January'])
...
>>> jan_month
['Sun', 'Sun', 'Sun', 'Sun']
```

Comment: still getttig an error  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m5l6DbRymIWK7U5u9Y45QeGXbMzwqLbY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes but it is working , it is not getting the key that's why it is throwing an error in your code.May be your dict_month is not correct and does not contain any key with name 'January'

Comment: Why is it not getting the key?

Comment: Show your dict_month value which you are assigning to x in your code(the code which you have shared on drive).