# how to by pass Python key error even when key is present?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, keyerror

error [image]

python [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186968/error-while-iterating-through-a-list/49187208?noredirect=1#comment85380012_49187208)

I am getting an key error even when there's a key present.

```
print (dict_month[0:4])
```

> [{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]

```
'January' in dict_month
```

> False

```
'january' in dict_month
```

> False

Comment: or `'January' in i for i in dict_month`

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary ... January is not a key of dict_month, it's a key for all of your dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner :

```
>>> any(['January' in ele for ele in l])
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [{'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}, {'January': 'Sun'}]

OUT : True
```

The problem with your approach was as A.Joly mentioned, that you have a `list of dictionary`. Your approach would have been correct for a `dictionary`.