# How to correctly return an output dictionary in Zapier Code (Python)?

Tags: python, api, integration-testing, zapier

I followed Zapier code documentation for Python but I'm still having this issue:

**Objective:**

I'm trying reformat my input(Feets) from Acuity Scheduling and update it on Salesforce.

**Code:**

```
if " ' " in input_data['Feets']:
output = {'Feets':Feets.split("'")[0],'Inches':Feets.split("'")[1]}
else
output = {'Feets':Feets,'Inches':Inches}
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Update:**

I updated the code but now I'm not able to get the output in the later steps.

**Input:**

```
if "'" in input_data['Feets']:
      output = {'Feets': input_data['Feets'].split("'")[0],'Inches':input_data['Feets'].split("'")[1]}
elif "," in input_data['Feets']:
      output = {'Feets': input_data['Feets'].split(",")[0],'Inches':input_data['Feets'].split(",")[1]}
else:
      output = {'Feets': input_data['Feets'],'Inches': input_data['Inches']}
```

**Error message:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpMwZDgy/usercode.py", line 8, in the_function
    if "'" in input_data['Feets']:
KeyError: 'Feets'

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk3Nd.png)

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. You've got two issues:

1. You're missing a `:` for your else, causing the python to not parse correctly
2. In your if, you don't want spaces around the `"'"`
3. You need to read input from the `input_data` dict

The following code works as expected:

```
if "'" in input_data['Feets']:
    output = {'Feets': input_data['Feets'].split("'")[0], 'Inches': input_data['Feets'].split("'")[1]}
else:
    output = {'Feets': input_data['Feets'],'Inches': input_data['Inches']}
```

Comment: Great! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: Hi David, I updated the code but now it's not working anymore. You have any tips for me?

Comment: In your screenshot, it shows that you've got invalid syntax. you need to make sure to indent the lines after the `elif` statement

Comment: I updated the original question again as this is still not working. Can you check the new error msg please?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python). You need to either always make sure `input_data['Feets']` is present or be more defensive when checking for it (using `input_data.get('Feets', '<default>')`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on input_data['Feets'] is present? Isn't already present?

Comment: `input_data` is the data mapped into this function from a previous step (shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49vTu.png)). In your example it might have data, but when the zap runs for real, the previous step that provides the `Feets` number might be missing data, so python throws a `KeyError`. I've made a basic example here: https://repl.it/repls/FirebrickMedicalInfo