# Error on getting request param from Django Rest Framework and Datatables

Tags: django, datatables, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use DRF and Datatables to populate a table with a large amount of data, with server-side processing.

Below is my view:

```
class ProductsListAPIView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Product.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-timestamp")
        return qs

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        draw = int(self.request.GET["draw"])
        start = int(self.request.GET["start"])
        length = int(self.request.GET["length"])

        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset[start:start+length]
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        result = {"draw": draw,
                  "recordsTotal": queryset.count(),
                  "recordsFiltered":queryset.count(),
                  "data": serializer.data}
        return Response(result)
```

This the script for the Datatables and Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#exampleAjax2').dataTable( {
         "autoWidth": true,
         "displayLength": 10,
         "lengthChange": false,
         "ordering": false,
         "processing": true,
         "searching": false,
         "serverSide": true,
         "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing to display",
            "info": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
            "infoEmpty": ""
        },
         "ajax": {
             "processing": true,
             "url": "/my-products/",
             "dataSrc": ""
         },
       "columns": [....],
     });
 });
```

I get the following error:  `KeyError: 'draw'`

Probably it means that I don't use the proper way to get the parameter.
Although, that's my first attempt at DRF and Datatables with server-side processing, so it's possible there are other mistakes too.

Answer (score 1):

It's should be:

```
"url": "/my-products/?draw=0&start=0&length=0"
```

in Ajax and :

```
draw = int(self.request.GET.get("draw", 0))
start = int(self.request.GET.get("start", 0))
length = int(self.request.GET.get("length", 0))
```

in DRF

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyError` in python is pretty straightforward. In your case , `self.request.GET["draw"]` statement tries to return the value `draw` but `draw` 
 is not found in the set of existing keys.

> **`KeyError`**
>
> Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the
>   set of existing keys.

The `request.GET` is a `dict` like object, So you can use [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to access values.

The syntax of `get()` is **`get(key,[default])`**.
So, it should be as

```
draw = int(self.request.GET.get("draw", default_val))
start = int(self.request.GET.get("start", default_val))
length = int(self.request.GET.get("length", default_val))
```

**Note**: If you doesn't provide **default_val**, `.get()` will return `None` if the Key doesn't exist

You can read more about [`KeyError` in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)