# How do I use the input function to call the value of a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-2.x

**Original Question**

This is written in Python 2 using Jupyter Notebook. I apologize in advance if the phrasing/terms are unconventional. I am a beginner & unaware of most coding conventions.

```
blue = 24
red = 18

color = input('What color would you like to know the value for? \n')
print (color)
```

I would like to be able to run the code, input 'blue' and have it print 24.

**EDIT:**

Ideally, I would like to not have to build a dictionary. This is a simplification of my actual code. I already have many, many variables defined (some definitions requiring user input) and it would be very inconvenient to have to create a dictionary from which.

This is my (more realistic) code:

```
blue = input('What is the value of blue?')
green = input('What is the value of blue?')
cyan = blue*green

color = input('What color would you like to know the value for? \n')
print (color)
```

I would like to be able to run the code, input cyan and have it print the numerical value of the variable cyan.

example: run. input 3. input 5. input cyan. code prints 15

Comment: @SurajM completely wrong, especially considering there are already 3 different answers on how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw_input`. `input` will override the existing value in the good case, and in a worse case raise a `NameError`. Then try to retrieve the value from `locals()`:

```
blue = 24
red = 18

color = raw_input('What color would you like to know the value for? \n')
try:
   print locals()[color] 
except KeyError:
   print 'Color {} is not defined'.format(color)
```

**Note** that this is pretty much a hack, and using this way the user will be able to access **any** local variable defined. If you want to limit what the user can access then use a predefined dictionary like some of the other answers suggest.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I think I will create a dictionary before release but this definitely helps with the alpha.

Answer (score 0):

make it a dictionary

```
colour_dict = {'blue': 24, 'red': 18}

colour = input('what colour...')

print('your colour: ', colour, 'is number: ', colour_dict[colour])
```

Comment: Since OP is using Python 2.X, `raw_input` should be used instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !
You need to use conditional statement (if clause) to check that user input the value is `blue`. If its true then print the `blue` variable value.

**Code :**

```
blue = 24
red = 18

color = input('What color would you like to know the value for? \n')
if (color==blue):
    print(blue)
```

**Output :**

```
What color would you like to know the value for?                                                                       
blue                                                                                                                   
24
```

Comment: If OP will have 10 colors do you suggest to have 10 if statements?

Comment: nope. In that case, the best solution is to declare the dictionary & get the value of dictionary through its key.
I give the solution according to the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary for this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

options = {"blue":24, "red":18}

answer = raw_input('What color would you like to know the value for? \n')

print(options[answer])
```

You could access the variable literally with `eval` or from `locals`. But that's generally considered a bad idea unless you actually have no other option. I'd also argue it's more complicated for no real reason.

An explanation of what's happening:

We create a new dictionary called options, with "blue" and "red" as it's keys and 24 and 18 as it's values respectively.

Now when we want our answer we can access it with `options[answer]` which is the same as `options["blue"]` since I gave "blue" as an answer to input.

Result:

```
What color would you like to know the value for? 
blue
24
```

Notes:

If you're running python 2 use `raw_input` instead of `input`.
This is a very simple solution, and if the user inputs anything other than "blue" or "red" the script will raise a `KeyError`. I'd start with [I'm getting Key error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python) for notes on how to deal with that.