# Weird error in while running a python code?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am running the below code, but python is giving some weird error which it was not giving before:

```
 for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['event_name'][i] == 'subcategory_click':
        df.at[i,'subcategory_navigation']=1
```

Input:

```
user_id event_name
10     psuedo_App_start
10     subcategory_click
10     subcategory_click
10     subcategory_click
10     product_search
10     product_search
10     product_search
```

Desired Output:

```
user_id event_name  subcategory_navigation
10     psuedo_App_start     0
10     subcategory_click    1
10     subcategory_click    1
10     subcategory_click    1
10     product_search       0
10     product_search       0
10     product_search       0
```

PFA the error image:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm getting Key error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)

Comment: `print(repr(df))` to see what is in there. `KeyError` indicates that either `'event_name'` doesn't exist in `df`, or `i` doesn't exist in `df['event_name']`. Do `print(df['event_name'])` to figure out which one it is.

Comment: You are iterating over the "indices" of `df`, not `df['event_name']`. If you didn't have that problem before, it was a coincidence.

Comment: Use `for i in range(len(df['event_name']))`, or better `for i, ev in enumerate(df['event_name']): if ev == 'product_search': a = i`.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be saying that `df` does not contain a key named `'event_name'`.  The error could also be due to `i` not existing in `df['event_name']`, but it appears that you'd expect that collection to be a list, not a map.

I see a potential problem in your logic. You're iterating based on the length of `df`, but then you're referencing a different list in your loop, `df['event_name']`. I don't see where the lengths of these two lists should be related. Do you maybe want `for i in range(len(df['event_name'])` ? - from your code, the length of `df` does not seem to be a valuable quantity, as it is a map, and you're referring that map's keys explicitly.

It's hard to know what's going on because you don't show us what `df` is. I'd suggest that you run the code in a debugger, stop on that line, and see what df contains at that point.

Answer (score 0):

```
df["subcategory_navigation"] = (df["event_name"] == "subcategory_click").astype(int)
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Try switching ['event_name'] and [i] in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

df.reset_index(inplace=True) .. I used this before the for loop, somehow it worked