# Parse json dict results in Key-error - python

Tags: python, json

I have json dicts that I want to parse and get the values, but I get a key error as the dictionary doesn't exist. How can I pass on to the next loop.

The id =123 has the following json data

```
json_dict = {       
"ABC" :"qwe",
"Students": [
 { 
  "Sub1": {
   "Details": {
   "Custom": { 
   "Name":"Amit Goenka" 
     }
    }
   }
 }
}
```

The id =345 has the following json data

```
json_dict = {        
"ABC" :"qwe",
"Students": [
 { 
  "Sub1": {
   "Details": {
    }
   }
 }
}
```

My code:

```
id_l = ["123","345","324"]
for id in id_l:
  for data in json_dict['Students']:
       val = data.get('Sub1')
       val2 = data['Sub1']['Details']['Custom']
       if val2:
          print("Name exists")
       else:
         print("no Name")
         continue
```

I get Key error for ID = 345 as there is no "Custom" data.

Comment: But `id =345` has no `"Custom"` key. What do you want to happen in this case?

Comment: I see not usage of `id` in your code at all

Comment: check out `.get()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting Key error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)

Comment: So, `if` the key `'Custom'` is `not in data['Sub1']['Details']`, it should not be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that a key exists in a dict using `in`. Your example would look something like this:

```
id_l = ["123","345","324"]
for id in id_l:
    for data in json_dict['Students']:
        val = data.get('Sub1')
        if 'Custom' in val['Details']:
            print("Name exists")
        else:
            print("no Name")
            continue
```

Also, note that `data.get('Sub1')` is similar to `data['Sub1']`, but it returns `None` if  `'Sub1'` is missing from `data` instead of raising a `KeyError`. Without additional error handling, this code will fail if `'Sub1'` is missing from `data`.

Comment: I didn't think about using "custom" in if statement. Thanks, it works and it is good learning for me. Sorry I did not include the "Sub1" data, was more curious to the point I was missing.