# I'm getting keyerror in python . "Exception has occurred: KeyError 'labels'"

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, pytorch, keyerror

In my python program I'm getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'labels'
KeyError: 'labels'
```

I'm getting error from this code:

```py
labels = data['labels'].reshape(-1).astype(np.int32)
```

Can anyone please help me out of this problem?

Comment: The error is saying that `data` does not have a key `"labels"`. What is `data`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting Key error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)

Comment: Are you sure that there is key  `labels` in `data`? Try to `print(data.keys()` and check.