# Issue: KeyError: normaltime

Tags: python, json

I stumbled across the problem. For 'normaltime', 'display' and 'current' it gives me the same error, which is on the picture below. The code stops if it finds the match, that has no value of the score. The value should be a number, but it is empty. I need this value or if it doesn't exist print value 999.

Image:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5aAL.png) <- click here and check the error code KeyError: 'normaltime'

```
import requests 
import json
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/football/scheduled-events/2024-02-01"

payload = ""
headers = {
    "authority": "api.sofascore.com",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "origin": "https://www.sofascore.com",
    "referer": "https://www.sofascore.com/",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/106.0.0.0"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

jsondata = json.loads(response.text)

for game in jsondata['events']:
    league = game['tournament']['name']
    hometeam = game['homeTeam']['name']
    awayteam = game['awayTeam']['name']
    round = game['roundInfo']['round']
    homescore = game['homeScore']['normaltime']
    awayscore = game['awayScore']['normaltime']
    homehalf = game['homeScore']['period1']
    awayhalf = game['awayScore']['period1']
    time = game['startTimestamp']

    print(league,"|", hometeam," - ",awayteam,"(",homehalf,"-",awayhalf,")",homescore,"-",awayscore,"|",datetime.fromtimestamp(time),"|",round)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting Key error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use `round` as a variable key as its a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) used in the Python language.

Instead run and account for missing data using `.get()` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)) instead as all game data won't be the same.

```
...
for game in jsondata["events"]:
    league = game["tournament"]["name"]
    hometeam = game["homeTeam"]["name"]
    awayteam = game["awayTeam"]["name"]
    game_round = game.get("roundInfo")
    round_name = "Not Started"
    if game_round is not None:
        round_name = game_round.get("name")
        if round_name is None:
            round_name = f"Round of {game_round['round']}"
    homescore = game["homeScore"].get("normaltime")
    awayscore = game["awayScore"].get("normaltime")
    homehalf = game["homeScore"].get("period1")
    awayhalf = game["awayScore"].get("period1")
    time = game["startTimestamp"]

    print(
        league,
        "|",
        hometeam,
        " - ",
        awayteam,
        "(",
        homehalf,
        "-",
        awayhalf,
        ")",
        homescore,
        "-",
        awayscore,
        "|",
        datetime.fromtimestamp(time),
        "|",
        round_name,
    )
```

Also probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python).

Comment: Is it possible to print out only the name if it exists, but if it doesn't exist print out the round number?
example: 
{'round': 5, 'name': 'Round of 16', 'cupRoundType': 8}  -  print only 'Round of 16'
{'round': 16} - print only '16'

Comment: Edited the answer to show how you would go about doing that.